# How to calculate target image size for PIL's perspective transform

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, transformation

I am currently correcting an image's perspective by performing a perspective transform based on the points of a 2d barcode embedded in the image.

The code I am using is below, and works perfectly.  The first function is a function I found to calculate the coefficients I need for the transform:

```
def find_coeffs(pa, pb):
matrix = []
for p1, p2 in zip(pa, pb):
    matrix.append([p1[0], p1[1], 1, 0, 0, 0, -p2[0]*p1[0], -p2[0]*p1[1]])
    matrix.append([0, 0, 0, p1[0], p1[1], 1, -p2[1]*p1[0], -p2[1]*p1[1]])

A = numpy.matrix(matrix, dtype=numpy.float)
B = numpy.array(pb).reshape(8)

res = numpy.dot(numpy.linalg.inv(A.T * A) * A.T, B)
return numpy.array(res).reshape(8), res
```

The following is the code that is supposed to do the transform:

```
firstPagePath = readFile(imagePath, '0', jobid, 0, 300)
d_id, barcode_points  = getIDFromBarcode(firstPagePath)
img = Image.open(imagePath)
width, height = img.size
top_x = min(barcode_points[0][0], barcode_points[1][0])
top_y = min(barcode_points[0][1], barcode_points[3][1])
bot_x = max(barcode_points[2][0], barcode_points[3][0])
bot_y = max(barcode_points[1][1], barcode_points[2][1])
new_points = [(top_x, top_y), (top_x, bot_y), (bot_x, bot_y), (bot_x, top_y)]
img.transform(img.size, Image.PERSPECTIVE, coeffs, Image.BICUBIC).save(imagePath)
```

The code does transform the image properly, but it clips the image to the size defined by img.size.  I would like to calculate the resulting size of the image before I do the transformation so that it does not clip.  Any ideas?